# how do i get styled-components to work with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
 
export const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  margin: 20px;
`;
```

Im trying to eddit the button but it does not respond.how do i give the button the margin?

Answer (score 0):

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
 
export const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  && {
       margin: 20px;
     }
`;
```

Try it like this this guy explanes how you can use it in multiple ways

https://www.sipios.com/blog-tech/how-to-use-styled-components-with-material-ui-in-a-react-app

Answer (score 0):

You would need to override the values for *Material UI*.

*Styled Components* recommends adding ampersands as stated here: *(which you should follow)*
https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
 
export const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  &&& {
       margin: 20px;
     }
`;
```

Another way to do that (which i often use) is to simply add `!important` next to your code.
So it would be something like:

```
margin: 20px !important;
```